# Zip column of lists in pandas series/dataframe with fixed list

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to zip a column of lists (in a data frame) with a fixed list. The objective is to multiply the hours, minutes, and seconds by 3600, 60, and 1 to get the total number of seconds.

Example:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data = ['01:02:03','12:23:34'], columns = ['Time'])
```

This data looks like:

```
       Time
0  01:02:03
1  12:23:34
```

I can split each of these into a list item, e.g. `pd.DataFrame(df.Time.str.split(":", expand = False))`, which gives:

```
           Time
0  [01, 02, 03]
1  [12, 23, 34]
```

Then I would like to `zip` each of these with the list `[3600, 60, 1]`, multiply the pairs, and then sum the results. I have tried to do this with the following code:

```
df = df.assign(Time = sum([a*b for a,b in zip([3600,60,1], [int(i) for i in df.Time.str.split(":", expand = True)])]))
```

But I cannot do `[int(i) for i in x]` because it iterates over the pandas series `df.Time.str.split(":", expand = False)` and tries to convert each list, when in fact I want the items in the list to be converted to integers. However, I'm not even sure this is the right way to zip a single list (`[3600, 60, 1]`) with multiple lists.

Desired output:

```
    Time_seconds
0           3723
1          44614
```

NB: in this case "time" is elapsed time, not a time of the day.

Comment: While `total_seconds()` does solve my immediate problem, it doesn't help with the more general case of zipping lists within series or data frames.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can directly use below one

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data = ['01:02:03','12:23:34'], columns = ['Time'])
df['Total_Sec']=pd.to_timedelta(df.Time).dt.total_seconds()
```

output:

```
        Time    Total_Sec
0   01:02:03    3723.0
1   12:23:34    44614.0
```